# Meaning of Erin

Tags: word-usage, translation

I usually come across the following combination a lot on online stores:
"Erin Recommendations" or "Erin Recommends"
Could anyone clarify the meaning? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it an acronym?

Comment: May be, but I don't think so.

Comment: Here is an example:https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/erin-recommendations

Comment: It's a name. The name of an author working for the company you just linked. Is this guerilla marketing?

Answer (score 1):

[Erin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Erin) is just someone’s given name.  For [most native speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Mary%E2%80%93marry%E2%80%93merry_merger), the female first name *Erin* is homophonic with the male first names *Aaron* and *Aron*.

The US Social Security Administration reports that it was the 28th most common first name for baby girls born in the United States [during the 1980s](https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/decades/names1980s.html), when it peaked. It first hit the top-100 list during the [1970s](https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/decades/names1970s.html), and was also common in the [1990s](https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/decades/names1990s.html) and the [2000s](https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/decades/names2000s.html) for girls born during those decades. It has become a less common choice since then.

I know many Erins in that age bracket.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erin), Erin is a Hiberno-English derivative of the Irish word "Éirinn". "Éirinn" is the dative case of the Irish word for Ireland. I don't work for Wikipedia, btw ;-)